# single application multiple environments in openshift

Tags: openshift

Is it possible to have single application multiple environments in openshift. I want to have environment like development, test and production in openshift. Is there a way to do this type of deployments automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely possible to accomplish this in Openshift. You can leverage jenkins to due your builds and git to create dev, test, prod branches.